# Mifare Desfire EV2 : master key sharing

Tags: mifare

I am designing a multi-purpose smartcard system using Mifare Desfire EV2.

I wonder if I have to share the master key with different usage managers, i.e. the door control manager, the food service manager if the card is used to pay the meal...

Is the card master key mandatory to read data on card applications ?

Thanks for tour help and happy Easter !

Answer (score 0):

It's called MiSmartApp which is basically a framework if I am correct. But even if I am wrong with that, you don't have to share the master key.